# Background color around text

Tags: html, css

How to set edges to be rounded like this .
[Example with rounded edges.](http://pokit.org/get/?6c55d7835757d1dff284799591178a1b.jpg)

```
<p>
  <span style="background-color: #9B3434;">
    <font color="white" face="Arial" >
       Dieses Feld darf nicht leer sein, geben Sie bitte die erforderliche Information ein.
    </font>
  </span>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/3KzK2/)**

Don't use `<font>` its a way back in early 90's html, instead style with css.

html

```
<p>
<span>Dieses Feld darf nicht leer sein, geben Sie bitte die erforderliche Information ein.</span>
</p>
```

css

```
p {
    padding: 7px;
    border: 2px dashed gray; /* to create a dashed border over the text */
    width: auto;
    display: inline;
}

span {
    background-color: #9B3434;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px; /* this gives the rounded look */
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 12px;
}

body {
    margin: 20px; /* for showing the example well, ignore this */ 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your example but why i don't get just the text rounded i don't need empty space. Is it the problem in my code above ? [Example](http://pokit.org/get/?447020181abca44260c553fbb5a5294f.jpg)

Comment: It because your tags are not closed properly. you should close your tags like `<p><span>.....<font>...</font></span></p>`. Basically <p> is a block element and it takes full width as block elements have tendency to take full width. So you get full width as your tags are not closed properly.

Comment: wait I edit your question and correct the tag closing

Answer (score 0):

Use "border-radius" tag  in the style ..!

eg

```
border-radius: 10px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
```

Comment: that only works for the newer browsers. please add information about how to do it in IE.

Answer (score 0):

It's called [Border Radius](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/rounded-corners/). There's several variations on it, so read up at that link.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="rounded">
    Lorem Ipsum Stuff
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.rounded {
    -moz-border-radius: 10px; /* For Firefox/Gecko Engine */
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px; /* For Safari + Chrome*/
    border-radius: 10px; /* For IE 9+*/
    background: #be4298;
    padding: 8px;
    width: 130px;
}
```

Note that [most browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=border-radius) now will only need to use `border-radius`, so unless you're absolutely certain that no old browsers will use your site, include the other two.

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fuzzball007/Q5Am7/)**